# Double Inputs In TextField When Running On Desktop

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows, flutter-textinputfield

I have a simple `TextField`  available [Here](https://github.com/Joshuaerinosho/TextFieldDoubleUp/blob/96a65c9a6e7af95bffd7c8249b5aabdccf64c23f/lib/main.dart#L45). It works as expected on the web, but when I run the app on Windows desktop, the `TextField`  inputs the character twice. For example, when I typed `x` and `1` I see `xx11`. This is an intermittent problem but happens often, and happens on many computers. I feel like this may be a Flutter bug because the behavior is different across platforms.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print(value);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

The full source code is available [here](https://github.com/Joshuaerinosho/TextFieldDoubleUp/blob/96a65c9a6e7af95bffd7c8249b5aabdccf64c23f/lib/main.dart#L1)

Web:
[image]

Desktop:
[image]

Comment: Try to Change 
  `final   _controller = TextEditingController();`
To 
`final  TextEditingController()  _controller = TextEditingController();`

Comment: I am getting the same issue. In our app, this happens all the time. When I run this sample, this only happens sometimes.

Comment: Also, sometimes, the input is really strange. Sometimes I cannot input anything at all.

Comment: I am getting this issue only with Korean characters. Maybe it is something with encoding.